# Нейронная сеть. Неверное обучение сети

Tags: python, нейронные-сети

Допустим есть значения погода: ср. температура дня, ср. давление, процент влажности и скорость ветра; нейронная сеть должна определить вероятность дождя в определенный день. Я использовал довольно часто используемый метод обратного распространения ошибки.

Код:

```py
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)

class NeuralNetwork(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.output = np.random.random((1, 1))
        self.output_delta = np.random.random((1, 1))
        self.input = np.random.random((2, 1))
        self.input_delta = np.random.random((2, 1))
        self.input_layer_weight = 3 * np.random.random((8, 1)) - 1
        self.ouput_layer_weight = 3 * np.random.random((2, 1)) - 1
        self.nu = 0.1

    @staticmethod
    def __sigmoid(x):
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

    @staticmethod
    def __derivative_of_sigmoid(x):
        return x * (1 - x)

    def train(self, train_inputs, train_outputs, train):
        for k in range(train):
            for i in range(len(train_inputs)):
                self.output = self.think(train_inputs[i])
                self.output_delta = train_outputs[i] - self.output
                self.input_delta = self.output_delta * self.ouput_layer_weight
                for j in range(len(self.input_layer_weight)):
                    self.input_layer_weight[j] = self.input_layer_weight[j] + (self.input_delta[0 if j % 2 == 0 else 1] * self.__derivative_of_sigmoid(self.input[0 if j % 2 == 0 else 1]) * train_inputs[i][j // 2] * self.nu)

                self.ouput_layer_weight = self.ouput_layer_weight + (self.output_delta * self.__derivative_of_sigmoid(self.output) * self.input * self.nu)


    def think(self, inputs):
        for i in range(len(self.input)):
            self.input[i] = self.__sigmoid(np.dot(inputs, [self.input_layer_weight[i], self.input_layer_weight[i + 2], self.input_layer_weight[i + 4], self.input_layer_weight[i + 6]]))

        return self.__sigmoid(np.dot(self.input.T, self.ouput_layer_weight))

with open("data", "r", encoding="utf8") as data:
    train_inputs = np.array(np.array([list(map(float, text.split()))[0:len(text.split()) - 1] for text in data])) #максимально загруженная строка
    data.seek(0)
    train_outputs = np.array(np.array([list(map(float, text.split()))[len(text.split()) - 1:len(text.split())] for text in data]))

neural_network = NeuralNetwork()

neural_network.train(train_inputs, train_outputs, 100)

print(neural_network.think(np.array([[1, 739, 0.86, 4]]))) #ответ должен стремиться к 1
```

Суть проблемы заключается в том, что при обучении, когда ей подаются данные при точном ответе 0, она стремится к 1. При этом в некоторых данных она обучается верно.

Есть 3 вопроса:  Сколько слоев должно быть в данном случае? Верно ли написана сеть? Возможно есть другие способы обучения?

Данные обучения (температура, давление, процент влажности, скорость ветра, ответ):

```
0 742 0.79 7 1
2 742 0.97 7 1
2 745 0.93 6 0
1 736 0.91 5 1
0 742 0.72 4 1
-3 753 0.9 2 0
-2 752 0.9 3 1
0 753 0.91 4 1
2 743 0.97 4 1
0 748 0.89 3 0
-1 747 0.91 2 1
1 748 0.73 6 0
3 741 0.88 5 1
1 750 0.94 2 1
2 752 0.88 7 0
4 748 0.9 7 1
3 755 0.97 4 0
2 755 0.89 2 0
0 754 0.83 4 0
2 755 0.87 6 1
5 742 0.9 7 1
1 734 0.8 8 1
-4 742 0.52 8 0
3 743 0.89 6 1
```

Comment: Не могу найти в коде, вы нормализовали данные?

Comment: Кол-во слоёв нужно подбирать, ну я смотрю сначала какой объём выборки, сколько у вас замеров есть? Ну если у вас очень мало данных, то естественно и слоёв немного (2-4), а вообще тут эмпирически нужно пробовать, как раз и начиная с 2-4 и до 15-20 и нейронов 8-256

Comment: А ещё, я бы сначала бы по быстрому подобрал наилучшую модель в Keras (для прямо наилучшей точности можно было бы использовать Grid Search от scikit-learn, которая будет сама подбирать гиперпараметры и алгоритмы оптимизации для вашей модели), а вот только потом её закодить

Comment: О каких данных идёт речь: о входных или выходных. Т. е. нормализировал ли я данные для обучения? Или про выходные: "провел" ли я выходные данные каждого нейрона через функцию? Ответ на последний вопрос - да.

Comment: На входе и выходе должны быть вещественные числа от 0 до 1 или от -1 до 1. Если вы подаёте на вход своей НС например "2; 742; 0.97; 7; 1" и затем начинаете просчёт - это ошибка, вам надо найти для каждого столбца максимум и затем просто все столбцы делить на соответствующий максимум